# angularjs and jquery missing property

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement [this plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/A6MvqA/) which uses the `jquery-ui slider` along with `angularjs` but with `angular 1.4.4` instead of the existing `1.0.5`.
The problem is that when making this change I get the following error:

> TypeError: element.slider is not a function

in this line:

```
element.slider("value", parseInt(newVal,10));
```

When running with the chrome debugger I can see that `element` is of type `jqlite` even tough the `jquery` script is loaded before `angular`.
I've tried using static script files instead of using the cdns to avoid any loading issues but it didn't help.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure jquery-ui is being loaded. I can replicate the error by removing jquery-ui in your plnkr.

Comment: Looks like it's loaded since the URL is valid and without it the slider doesn't work regardless to the angular version